# Set Texture Addressing Mode to border color in DirectX9

Tags: c++, directx, texture-mapping, directx-9

I am trying to set the Texture Addressing Mode to border color in my DirectX application. According to [this](http://flylib.com/books/en/1.541.1.71/1/) source all I have to do is:

> call IDirect3DDevice7::SetTextureStageState
>   and pass the texture stage identifier as the first argument, the
>   D3DTSS_BORDERCOLOR stage state value as the second argument, and the
>   desired RGBA border color as the third argument

I try to use the following code:

```
m_device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_BORDERCOLOR, 0);
```

But I get a compilation error saying

> identifier "D3DTSS_BORDERCOLOR" is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Are you sure you want to use DirectX7?**

You document is too old, that's for DirectX7 which is deprecate now, you should use the following function in DirectX9

```
m_device->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_BORDERCOLOR, 0xffff0000) // red color
```

**Updated**:

In case you didn't set the correct address mode, here is the code for border mode.

```
m_device->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSU,  D3DTADDRESS_BORDER);
m_device->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSV,  D3DTADDRESS_BORDER);
```

Comment: Did not know that! However, the above code does not solve my problem. The Texture-Addressing Mode is still 'wrap'.

Comment: I guess you didn't set the correct addressing mode, see my update please.